# Particle sliding on a sphere with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, constrained-dynamics

This is a generalization of the question [Particle sliding on a sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262282/) when we also have friction given by $F_f = \mu N$.

See the following figure:

[image]

Before doing anything, we can imagine what friction will do. It is clear it will reduce the velocity and thus, delaying the "jumping" point from the sphere to a large angle $\theta_J$ (with respect to the vertical). I have tried two approaches:

**1) Numerically via Newton's equations**

Newton's equations:

$$r: \quad mg \cos(\theta) -N = m \dot{\theta}^2R $$
$$t: \quad mg \sin(\theta) - \mu N = m \ddot{\theta}R, $$
where $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

Substituting one into the other and rearranging I get:

$$\ddot{\theta} = \mu \dot{\theta}^2 + \frac{g}{R} \left( \sin{\theta} - \mu \cos {\theta} \right),$$
I believe this ODE equation does not have an analytical solution (at least that is what WolframAlpha says) so I have integrate it numerically considering $\theta(0) = 0$ and $\dot{\theta}(0) = 0$ as the boundary conditions, as well as requiring the friction force to be smaller than the weight projection in the tangential direction (otherwise the particle won't move).

Then I have computed numerically the moment where the normal $N$ is zero for the first time, that is, for the "jumping" angle $\theta_J$ and velocity $\dot{\theta}_J$ :
$$N(\theta_J, \dot{\theta}_J) = mg \cos \theta_J - mR\dot{\theta_J}^ 2 = 0.$$
From this condition I have been able to extract the "jumping" angle and velocity in function of $\mu$, $\theta_J (\mu)$ and $\dot{\theta_J}(\mu)$. Suprisingly, after all this "complex" computations I got what seems linear relationships for  $\theta_J (\mu)$ and $\dot{\theta_J}(\mu)$ (for $m=1$, $R=1$, $g = 9.8$, $\theta_0 = 0.57º$ and
$\dot{\theta}_0 = 1.5 \text{ rad/s}$ ):
[image]
[image]
For the first plot, the linear fit is given by:
$$ \theta_J = a\mu + b $$
for $a=21.07 \pm 0.3$ and $b=42.0$. The interceipt $b$ is the value expected for $\theta_J (\mu = 0)$, which is given by (from the problem without friction):
$${\theta_J}(\mu = 0) = \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{2}{3} + \frac{{\dot{\theta}_0}^2R}{3g}\right) = 42.0.$$

This *linear behaviour* stands out as the ODE is highly nonlinear! So I suspect there might be a simpler way to compute the "jumping" points which avoids computing the full trajectory and makes use of the "jumping" condition given by $N(\theta_J, \dot{\theta}_J) = 0$ to get (perhaps) an **analytical linear solution** for $\theta_J (\mu)$ and $\dot{\theta_J}(\mu)$?

**2) Via Energy conservation**
Following the non-friction case, the easier way to compute it is considering energy conservation to find a relationship between the "jumping" velocity and angle  $\dot{\theta_J} (\theta_J)$. I have tried it but I get stuck. I started considering the loss of mechanical energy is the work of the friction force:
$$\Delta E_m = W_{F_f}$$
Now, the left hand side is:
$$\Delta E_m = mgh_J - \frac{1}{2} m  v_J^2 = mgR(1- \cos \theta_J) - \frac{1}{2} m  R^2 \dot{\theta_J}^2,  $$
where $v_J$ is the linear jumping velocity and $h_J$ the height from the top of the sphere where the ball "jumps".

And the right hand side:
$$ W_{F_f} = \int_0^{\theta_J} F_f R d\theta = R m \mu \left( \int_0^{\theta_J} g \cos \theta d\theta - \int_0^{\theta_J} R \dot{\theta}^2 d\theta \right)  = R m \mu \left( g \sin \theta_J - R \int_0^{\theta_J} \dot{\theta}^2 d\theta \right), $$
where at the second equality I have substituted the expression for the normal $N(\theta, \dot{\theta})$. The question is how to approach this last integral... I substituted $\dot{\theta}^2$ from the 2nd order ODE from the previous approach and managed to integrate both terms and obtained the same expression as in the left hand side, basically finding that $$ 1 = 1,$$ which is not very useful.

**QUESTION:** *Any ideas or approaches to solve this problem with an apparent simple solution? Is it true that $\theta_J (\mu)$ and $\dot{\theta_J}(\mu)$ follow linear relationships or is it just an artifact of the range studied and farther out the functions have different behaviours?*

---

*Comment:* I have to say too I am using as initial conditions $\theta_0 = 0.57º$ and $\dot{\theta}_0 = 1.5 \text{ rad/s}$ so the particle does not get stuck before moving. That is because it will only move if, initially (which is the worse case), $W_t > F_f$, for $W_t$ the tangential weight. This implies there is a condition for a maximum $\mu$ given $\theta_0$ and $\dot{\theta}_0$:
$$ \mu \leq \mu_\text{max} \equiv \frac{g \sin \theta_0}{g \cos \theta_0 - \dot{\theta}_0^ 2 R}.$$
For the initial conditions taken, $\mu_\text{max} = 0.0129$.

Comment: The residuals don't look randomly distributed about that line - the points are first consistently below, then consistently above, then consistently below, the line. It seems far more likely to me that the line is merely a good approximation for what's going on.

Comment: @probably_someone see my edit. I think the first plots might have some small fluctuations which might be biased because of the method of computation.

Comment: Check your simulation, I think that sum think is wrong, because if the friction coefficient get larger  the angle must be smaller? I also did the simulation the result is “quasi linear “

Comment: The log scale actively undermines what you're trying to show. If you're trying to make the point that something looks linear, you should show that the _differences between the data and the line_ are randomly distributed about zero, and that these differences are consistent with zero to within the uncertainties of the simulation. The log scale _hides_ these differences for higher values of $\mu$, and it also distorts them: adding 0.01 to a point will move it a different distance than subtracting 0.01. In any case, see the answer I posted.

Comment: @Eli I think it is the opposite, a higher friction means the particle will stay more time in the sphere and leave at a larger angle (the angle is with respect to the top of the sphere)

Comment: the condition to stop the simulation is $N= 0$ right ?

Comment: @Eli More or less yes, first I compute the trajectory of the particle until some given time and then I find the point with the smallest normal value.

Comment: @Puco4 Can you post your actual data behind each plot?

Comment: @Puco4 Also, what unit is $\theta_J$ in on these plots?

Comment: @probably_someone $\theta_J$ is in degrees.

Comment: I must say that using notation $\dot\theta_J$ for the angular velocity at the jumping point is somewhat confusing. It looks like you are saying $\dot\theta_J=\frac{\text d}{\text dt}\theta_J$ rather than $\dot\theta_J=\dot\theta(t_J)$ where $t_J$ is the time of jumping. Perhaps $\omega_J$ would be better?

Comment: @AaronStevens Feel free to update the notation if you want!

Answer (score 1):

This is my simulation result , so I don't see the linearity .
the simulation is done with Maple program where I stop the simulation if the normal force N is less then zero.

[image]

**Edit:**
I did the simulation with this equations

Position Vector is :

$$R= r\,\left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \varphi  \right) 
\\\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \end {array}
 \right] 
$$

so I get this equations  of motions   (Euler Lagrange)

$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}\varphi  \left( \tau \right) - \left( -{
\frac {\mu\,\sin \left( \varphi  \left( \tau \right)  \right) }{r}}-{
\frac {\cos \left( \varphi  \left( \tau \right)  \right) }{r}}
 \right) g-\mu\, \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}\varphi  \left( \tau
 \right)  \right) ^{2}
=0$$

and the normal force:

$$N=m \left(  \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}\varphi  \left( \tau \right) 
 \right) ^{2}r-g\sin \left( \varphi  \left( \tau \right)  \right) 
 \right) 
$$

Data :

$\varphi(0)=\pi/2\,,D(\varphi)(0)=0$

$g=9.8$

$r=1$

for each $\mu$ the simulation run and stop when $N\le 0.001$

Least-square fit give you

$\varphi_l=0.0098+1.006\mu$

Comment: yeah, maybe I kept with a too low $\mu$ regime... Just for clarification, could you add a linear regression in your plot to visualize? Then I will accept as correct the answer.
But I will try first too to get to higher $\mu$ to see if I find the same, did you use the same values for the initial conditions?

Comment: I really don't understand how can you get to $\mu= 0.3$ with the same initial conditions I wrote, because for the particle to start moving has to fulfill $F_f < W_t$, where $W_t$ is the tangential weight and this gives a maximum value for $\mu$: $\mu_{\text{max}} < \frac{g \sin \theta_0}{g\cos \theta_0 - \dot{\theta}_0^2 R}$, which for my initial conditions is $0.0129$

Comment: @Puco4 I add more information for you

Comment: thank you for you answer, but I still have a couple of doubts:
1) i believe you compute the Normal with a negative value, as the normal should be equal to the weight in the radial coordinate - the centripetal acceleracion, not the other way around.
2) I continue without understanding how you can manage to take this initial conditions and compute until this $\mu$, which violates equation from Comment1 (edit 1). You are in a regime where the friction force dominates the weight!!

Comment: To question 1 my friction force is $\mu\,N$ so if N is negative it is ok. I don’t have yet answer for your question 2

Comment: Also, I see you use a different angle definition than me, that is your $\varphi$ is with respect to the horizontal and my $\theta$ is respect to the vertical. Then I don't understand your plot as you get similar values than me and increasing values with $\mu$, while you should observe decreasing values of the angle $\varphi$ according to the reason I told you before: larger friction means less velocity and leaving the sphere later (or your plot is my angle $\theta$?).

Comment: My initial condition is also different. I star at $\pi/2$

Comment: well, is the same than me then because your $\pi/2$ is my $0$.

Comment: I admit that with your equation I can’t get the same result, this is why I change the coordinates